# My JavaScript file is not being called by the HTML file when I specify the type as module in the <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html, module

I am trying to make a JavaScript file a module, but that stops the html from calling the JavaScript file. When I don't make it a module it calls the code and it works as expect, printing Start Successful in the console. I am trying to call a JavaScript file through the html file with the type module (Just like it would do without the type module).

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
          <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js. Nothing happens when I run it

```
console.log("Start Succesful");
```

If the html file is like this, the only difference being i have not declared a type in the script tag, it prints Start "Successful" in the console

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
          <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Details:
I am using visual studio code
It might be something I need to do in a Json file, but I don't know what that would be
I want to be clear it does work if I don't declare the type in the html script tag
The same code works in repl.it but not visual studio code, I am assuming the problem has little
to do with the syntax (maybe related to it) and has something to do with extensions settings or something I don't know anything about. I will be very happy with a link to what I should search or the topic I need to know more about. Please tell me if I am not being clear

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It could be the way the path is written:

If the HTML and javascript files are in the same folder.
Instead of:

```
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
```

You can try:

```
    <script type="module" src="./script.js"></script>
```

and it should import correctly, in case that is the answer. You can use Visual Studio Code's automatic path completion in the future.

Comment: That didn't work, vs code knew which file I was referring to. When I clicked the follow path it sent me to the right file. It will not run the file when I make its type module, if I don't make it a module it runs perfectly fine.

Comment: What if you try to add an event listener to trigger the script when the page loads?

In "scripts.js":

`
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    console.log("Test");
});
`